# Convert Cobertura.xml to html report

Tags: node.js, cobertura, istanbul, nyc

Is it possible to convert a cobertura.xml file to an html report or similar, so it can be viewed locally?  I already have it pretty-printing in Jenkins but we need it locally too...

The report has been produced using istanbul/nyc, and the code it's producing coverage for is in node.js.

Answer (score 1):

[pycobertura](https://pypi.org/project/pycobertura/) ([repository](https://github.com/aconrad/pycobertura)) answers your need of converting a Cobertura XML report into an human-friendly HTML page:

```
pycobertura show --format html --output coverage.html cobertura.xml
```

Then open `coverage.html` in your browser to check the report.